# Flutter Stack positioning and overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on flutter. I am using stack for stack 2 widgets. But i have some problems.

This is what I am trying to do.

[image: This is what I am trying to do.]

But my widgets look like this.

[image: But my widgets look like this.]

That's my code:

```
class UpcomingSessionItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/yoga-1.jpg')),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "9 am - 10:30 am",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text("Yoga for Beginners with Emily Cassel")
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Answers belong as answers, not as edits to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap your Container(Widget) which is inside the stack with the Positioned Widget and set the bottom, left, and right attributes. and you will get the output

You can try this code by copy-paste in your editor.

### Example Code here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackExampleState createState() => _StackExampleState();
}

class _StackExampleState extends State<StackExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25), child: Image.asset('assets/image.png')),
          Positioned(
            bottom: -50,
            right: 20,
            left: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "TITLE",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Hey, There?",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "This is the example",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Column`

```
 return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/yoga-1.jpg')),
            Container(
              height: 50, //Any space you want
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "9 am - 10:30 am",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text("Yoga for Beginners with Emily Cassel")
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution moved from the question to an answer:

> I changed this:
>
> ```
> alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter
> ```
>
> to this:
>
> ```
> alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center
> ```
>
> and I wrapped my container with Positioned widget and I changed `bottom:0` property

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Padding` for the container which is on top. Like this:

```
Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
   child: Container(
      height: 100,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "9 am - 10:30 am",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text("Yoga for Beginners with Emily Cassel")
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
)
```